# What's micronaut-cli.yml for?

Tags: micronaut

When I generate a new Micronaut project using the `mn` CLI tool or [Micronaut Launch](https://micronaut.io/launch/), it comes with a `micronaut-cli.yml` file specifying an `applicationType`, `defaultPackage`, `testFramework`, `sourceLanguage`, `buildTool`, and `features`. Yet if I delete this file, alter it, or even replace it with invalid YAML, my project still seems to build and run just fine.

Presumably the `mn` CLI itself can't possibly use this file for anything either, since it looks like it only supports project *creation* commands - nothing for editing existing projects. At least, I only see those when I run `mn --help` in my home directory.

So what's `micronaut-cli.yml` for? Does it actually affect anything at all? Or is it just a historical record of how the project was created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Presumably the `mn` CLI itself can't possibly use this file for anything either, since it looks like it only supports project *creation* commands - nothing for editing existing projects.

It isn't true that the CLI itself can't possibly use the file.  It does.  It also isn't true that the cli only supports project creation commands.  The CLI supports other commands. To see a list of commands available in your project, run `mn --help` from inside the directory containing the `micronaut-cli.yml` file.

> So what's micronaut-cli.yml for?

It is a config file for the CLI.

> Does it actually affect anything at all? Or is it just a historical
> record of how the project was created?

The former.

As an example set `testFramework` to `junit` and run `create-test`.  Then change `testFramework` to `spock` and run the same command.

Comment: @mark-amery If you have questions about what specific settings in that file are for, feel free to add that to your question.

Comment: Some of the relevant code is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-starter/blob/85c4cff23f8e47b608c8bc6f2b30d4b854761d79/starter-cli/src/main/java/io/micronaut/starter/cli/CodeGenConfig.java.

Comment: Aha - I'd run `mn --help`, seen only application creation commands listed, and assumed nothing else existed. Was about to reply that `mn create-test` just gives me an error message suggesting that I might've meant `create-app` or `create-cli-app`. But if I run `mn --help` from *in the directory* with `micronaut-cli.yml` - and no deeper - then suddenly I have more options I never knew existed! Now things make sense!

Comment: Awesome. The gist at https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/c6471bbf3eb652fafe94ad6119949d20 and the docs at https://docs.micronaut.io/3.5.2/guide/#commands are relevant.

Comment: I've edited my question to hopefully make my mistake of not running `mn --help` from within the project root immediately obvious to a future reader landing here (and hopefully do so without invalidating anything written in this answer), and have edited here to update the quote and indicate that other commands are available if you run `mn` from the project root. Hopefully that's all welcome and helpful!

Comment: You changed what I was quoting, which is fine.  For future readers if there is confusion, please review history of the question and the answer.  Thanks for your help @MarkAmery.